# How to remove some children html element and loop through parents to show remaining elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all available `div.finput` parents and loop through them, then remove the `div.fsetting` children and leave the `div.form-group` element and append it to the result wrapper with `div.result`.

How can I achieve this?

```js
(($) => {
  generateForm()
})(jQuery);

function generateForm() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-generate', function(e) {
    let elementRows = $('.finput');
    // alert(elementRows.length)
    let html = '';

    $.each(elementRows, function(i, v) {
      html += elementRows.html();
    });

    $('.result').html(html);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="finput">
  <div class="fsetting">
    <button class="fexpand">edit</button>>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="firatname" id="firstname">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="finput">
  <div class="fsetting">
    <button class="fexpand">edit</button>>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
</div>

<button class="js-generate">generate</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

The appended element in `div.result` should look like this:

```html
<div class="result">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the HTML in your output example you can select the `.form-group` children of the `.finput` elements and `append()` them to `.result`. Then you can `remove()` the original `.finput` elements completely.

```js
(($) => {
  generateForm()
})(jQuery);

function generateForm() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-generate', function(e) {
    let $fInputs = $('.finput').remove();
    let $formGroups = $fInputs.children('.form-group');

    $('.result').append($formGroups);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="finput">
  <div class="fsetting">
    <button class="fexpand">edit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="firatname" id="firstname">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="finput">
  <div class="fsetting">
    <button class="fexpand">edit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
</div>

<button class="js-generate">generate</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Also note that the `(($) => {})(jQuery)` structure you're using is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), not a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event handler. The code is fine in this case as you're using a delegated event handler, however there's a meaningful difference between the two which may cause you issues if you're not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks, But there is a loop for the  total div.finput available, isn't necessary to loop them before outputting the result, there will be more than 2 div.finput. How this can be done?

Comment: You don't need the loop as the `$('.finput`') selector will find them all - the example above demonstrates this.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rory McCrossan